# Maximum distance between two consecutive points of N random points on a unit length line

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I have encountered a seemingly simple question on distances of random points.

Place N points randomly and uniformly on the line segment [0..1].
How to derive the expectation (or the distribution) of the "maximum"
distance between two consecutive points?

Just a reference would be very helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: this is an order statistics question try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the connection with algebraic geometry? Also, do you include distances from $0$ and $1$ or not? If you do, then there is a useful transformation: The $n+1$ gaps are uniformly distributed on the $n$-dimensional simplex of positive numbers summing to $1$.

Comment: This article computes some moments of the distribution for uniformly distributed random variables for comparison with distributions of primes: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1971-25-116/S0025-5718-1971-0299567-6/S0025-5718-1971-0299567-6.pdf I think more was known from much earlier, though.

Comment: Do you mean "consecutive" in the order in which the points were chosen,
or in their order in $(0,1)$?  E.g., if $N=3$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$
happens to be $(0.4, 0.6, 0.1)$, is the maximum distance
$\left|x_2-x_3\right| = 0.5$ or $0.4 - 0.1 = 0.3$?
(Or maybe $1 - x_2 = 0.4$, going by **Douglas Zare**'s suggestion?)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The points should be sorted. My original question is on random points placed on the circumference of length 1. But, for N->infinity, both cases are similar, I think.

Comment: To Zare, Thank you so much. I fixed the tags. What I want to know is the probability that the maximum distance is \Omega(f(N)/N) for e.g., f(N) = log N.

Comment: Another place the distribution is worked out is here using inclusion-exclusion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment. The variance isn't stated there, but I think the variance might also be simple. I think a related question, asking about the longest side of a random polygon inscribed in the unit circle, was asked on MO in the last few months.

Comment: Thank you again! Using inclusion-exclusion argument and Markov inequality, I can see that the probability that the largest gap is \Omega(log N/N) is \Omega(1).

Comment: The expectation is a well-known problem - see http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/594/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-longest-piece and the references in there.

Answer (score 5):

Let $S$ be the length of the longest interval and let $X$ be the largest random variable among $n=N+1$ iid exponential random variables with mean 1. We have $E[S] = E[X]/n$, where $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$.

From this paper:

L. Holst. On the lengths of the pieces of a stick broken at random. Journal of Applied Probability, 17(3):623–634, 1980.

Answer (score 3):

For $n$ random points on a circle, Theorem 1 of [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6114) provides an expression for the $m$th moment of the maximum distance, namely

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(d_{\max}\right)^m\right]=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+m-1)!}\sum_{\stackrel{r_1+2r_2+\ldots+m r_m}{r_i\in\mathbb{N}_0}}{\frac{m!}{r_1!1^{r_1}r_2!2^{r_2}\cdots r_m! m^{r_m}}H_{n,1}^{r_1}H_{n,2}^{r_2}\cdots H_{n,m}^{r_m}},
$$

where $H_{n,k}=\sum_{j=1}^n{j^{-k}}$ is the $n$th harmonic number of order $k$.